# Checkbox Insert / Delete From Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, checkbox

A little about my code:

I have code that dynamically displays emails with a checkbox next to each email.

```
<?   
    foreach($er as $row){ ?>
    <input name="emailcheckbox" id="emailcheckbox" type="checkbox" value="check" checked="checked">
    <?
    echo $row[email]."<br><br>";
    echo "<input name='emailID' id='emailID' type='hidden' value='".$row[emailID]."' />";       
    } $emailquery->execute(); ?>
```

I can't seem to come up with a way that deletes the emailID of each email from a specific database table when you uncheck the checkbox. When you re-check the checkbox, I want to insert it back into the database table.

The emails won't go away, because they are stored in a completely different table than the one I want to insert/remove it from.

I know this is kind of a full question, so I will answer any questions you may have. Thank you in advance for all your help!

Comment: Depending on how you want to go about it, you could use AJAX where you detect the checkbox being unticked and then call the server with it. Alternatively you can also submit it as POST(Dont use GET. Crawlers and webloaders will wreak havoc) and is !isset(EMAIL_ID), do your code to remove it. Though you will have to give each checkbox input its own unique name

Comment: to add to @aayush comment, you definitely **shoud** do this by AJAX. the potential for duplicates based on a user getting click-happy, or just large bandwidth consumption, are both very real. with AJAX you can disable the checkbox and wait for a response to re-enable, avoiding these issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, change your input to

```
<input name="emailcheckbox[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row[email]);?>" ...
```

so, after you post this form back to server you will have

```
$_POST['emailcheckbox'] == array('checkedemail1', 'checkedemail2'...)
```

so you will need to delete **all** e-mails from your table and insert emails from this array, with this you will delete unchecked ones and save only checked ones

Comment: The sledgehammer approach of deleting all then re-inserting is simple, but inelegant and possibly inefficient.  A hidden formfield with all the available checklist values will allow you to select which ones to delete.

Comment: @DanBracuk I agree, but want to note: if we have some emails in this table which are deleted from "main" table - they will stay abandoned

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```
<input name="emailcheckbox" id="emailcheckbox" type="checkbox" value="[tablename][email]" checked="checked">
```

Insert Page:

```
<?
foreach($_POST['emailcheckbox'] as $item)
{
$query = "INSERT INTO ".$item[0]." VALUES(".$item[1].")";
.....
}....
?>
```

Comment: this system will not delete "unchecked" ones